# how to create visual qr code in php and not simple qr code

Tags: php, qr-code

Dont know is this possible or not ? how to create visual qr code in php. Main thing i am asking visual qr code not Simple qr code..

I know how to create simple qr code. But I want to create visual qr code

Comment: What do you mean "simple qr"?

Comment: and what do you mean by "visual QR code" ?

Comment: Maybe something like the [Snapchat QR Codes](http://new.soldsie.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Snapchat-QR-Ghost-Code.jpg)

Comment: http://www.visualead.com/qr-code-generator/  like this

Comment: @AlexSlipknot simple in the sense using phpqr library or google script

Comment: simple like this ---> https://doyalpouchmachine.com/testimg/index.php

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find any solution in php but I think that you can implement it by yourself with existing qr-library. To do this you have to implement some method to add image and combine it with qr-generated code. Also you need to know how to combine image with black color - in this case qr-generated image must be in different color (white for example)

Comment: FAQ says:
Furthermore, if the QR Code is overlaid with an illustration or design, the resultant code may not be called a QR Code any longer, because there is no standard for doing this kind of operation. Although DENSO WAVE waives its rights to QR Codes as long as they follow the JIS or ISO standard, this is not necessarily the case with codes that do not follow the standard. DENSO WAVE may decide to exercise its patent rights against such codes. 
If you are contemplating arranging an illustration or design involving a QR Code, please consult with DENSO WAVE about your project beforehand.

Comment: @AlexSlipknot thanks for your quick response..... can you provide any example with qr library code.....

Comment: Here is an example based on qrlib: http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138613/discussion-between-user3198563-and-alex-slipknot).

Comment: that i knw sir please tell me something with image or transparent qr code with image